Not able to find app.module.ts file in my angular project
I am using latest version of angular in that i didn't find the app.module.ts file.
I can only see the below files. In my case I want app.module.ts.
https://i.imgur.com/LvUVOAb.png
when I'm manually adding the files I am facing so many errors.
so i want the file to be created while running the project creation command itself.
can anyone please help me to get app.module.ts file in my project.

With Angular v17, newly generated projects are standalone by default and don't include an app module anymore. The linked question gives guidance on how to handle apps without an app module, and how to create a fresh project with the latest Angular CLI version which still has an app module.

@JSONDerulo reopened because provided solution is outdated and not accepted, there is no --no-standalone

--no-standalone works perfectly for me still in v19. This is just a duplicate question.

@JSONDerulo missing in docs, but checked and it's present

@NarenMurali it's a general rule in the Angular CLI, that for boolean options, in order to set them to false you can prefix them with --no-. This is described in the docs. https://angular.dev/tools/cli#boolean-options
